# Cultural context for the book of James

Tags: james

What was going on culturally and historically at the time of the book of James.

Comment: Are you asking if James was addressing converted Israelites in a Roman-occupied Jerusalem between 33-49AD?

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.  This question is very broad and does not involve the analysis of the Bible text.

Comment: Are you asking a for 1st century history lesson?

Answer (score 2):

The book of James is written during the time of the Diaspora :

> ... to the twelve tribes scattered abroad ... [James 1:1 KJV],

which is documented in Acts :

> ... And at that time there was a great persecution against the church which was at Jerusalem ; and they were all scattered abroad throughout the regions of Judaea and Samaria, except the apostles. [Acts 8:1 KJV]

Both James and Peter (his first epistle) write to this situation but broaden their epistles to Jews scattered to further parts.

It is a time of transition. The first covenant is waxed old and is superseded by the New Testament. And it is a time of in-gathering : the gospel goes out to all of the Jewish nation but also goes further - to the Gentiles.

The New does not destroy the old, it supersedes it.